# GRASS r.statistics method=average for non-integer maps

Tags: grass-gis, spatial-statistics, average

I need use the functionality of r.statistics using the average method. I have one map with cell clumps for a base layer and another containing various non-integer cell values for a cover layer.

However, when I try I get this error

> "This module currently only works for integer (CELL) maps"

What alternative is there?

Comment: HelloWorld, Hi. Did you search in the manual page?

Comment: Sounds like zonal statistics to me. See for example https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.stats.zonal.html